# Calling Java SOAP webservice in HTML page

Tags: html, web-services, soap, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I am new to HTML development.
I am developing a mobile application using phonegap- HTML5.
I want to call a web service which is written in JAVA returning SOAP message.
I am calling my webservice using XmlHttp reguest but which on execution returns null data and status as 0.
So, my question is how can I call webservice in an HTML page?
What should I do to call Java SOAP webservice from HTML page?

Please any help is appreciated.
Please suggest any method soon.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Soap service do you use? What data service return? Do you exploit from service of Application Desktop or Web

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a soap request in a js file.

In your js file you should have something like this:

```
function sendSOAPRequest(webServiceMethod, params, callbackMethod, isAsynchronous, callContext)
{
//Get the token from local storage
var token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");

//Get the soap envelope with given parameters 
var soapEnvelope = getEnvelopeFromParam(webServiceMethod, params);
//Send the soap request
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.zzz.com/yyy/soap",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapEnvelope,
    context: callContext,
    complete: callbackMethod,
    async: isAsynchronous,
    timeout: 60000,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://zzz.com/yyy/uuu/Iooo/' + webServiceMethod);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);
    }        
});
}

function getEnvelopeFromParam(webServiceMethod, parameters)
{
var soapEnvelope = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><' + webServiceMethod + ' xmlns="http://zzz.com/yyy/uuu">';

$.each(parameters, function(key, value) {
    if(value)
    {
        soapEnvelope += '<' + key + '>' + value + '</' + key + '>';
    }
    else
    {   
        //Send a null value
        soapEnvelope += '<' + key + ' i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>';
    }
});

soapEnvelope += '</' + webServiceMethod + '></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

return soapEnvelope;
```

}

this is a method to call webservice. You have the specify the right adresses corresponding to your server.

Now include this js file in your html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.js"></script>
```

Now you have to call your js function from your html page (for exemple)

```
sendSOAPRequest("myfunction", params, endFunction, true, this);
```

And you have to define the endFunction

```
function endFunction(xmlHttpRequest, status)
{
   //Work with xmlHttpRequest and check status
}
```